# Svelte: bind:borderBoxSize not recognized in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm using Svelte's `bind:borderBoxSize` to keep track of my element's sizes, which is working great (compiles, runs & works as intended). For example:

```html
<div id="top" bind:borderBoxSize={$myBoxSize}>text</div>
```

However, it is not recognized by Visual Studio Code and I'm wondering if there is something I can do about it to either fix it or at least get rid of the error (it is cause me anxiety over time):

```
Property 'borderBoxSize' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2339)
```

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Svelte version is `3.59.1`, "Svelte for VS Code" is `107.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed by the newest version of the extension, which was [released yesterday](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/releases/tag/extensions-107.6.0).

> (feat) add support for resize observer bindings ([#2044](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/pull/2044/files))

(Also note that `contentBoxSize` is [currently broken](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8583).)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, this is the version which I have installed and I still get this error. :/

Comment: You are correct, there still is a type error. Issue has been reported. As a workaround it might be possible to extend the interface declarations locally but I cannot test this right now...

Comment: @Markstar: Bindings should not cause errors as of [v.107.7.0](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/releases/tag/extensions-107.7.0) ("fix: type one way bindings that are not the element ([#2066](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/2066))")

Comment: @H.R. Yes! The latest update does indeed fix the issue!